# Gmail email not recognized after adding plus sign when registering

Tags: email, gmail

I used the (gmail only?) feature of adding a plus sign in my email for filtering purposes like so:

> myemail+job@gmail.com

Registration with that email on a website went great but trying to sign in again returns an "account not found" error. Part of the url looks like this:

> ...login/?email=myemail+job@gmail.com...

Any suggestions? Or is this something that has to be remedied by a web admin?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the owner of the website, since the error is in their end.

But per your information, the error is using the GET request for handling logins, which is bad practice.

> GET requests go into browser history, are visible in the address bar, can be cached by proxies, etc. This violates both HTTP semantics and security. Just do login as per industry best practices and save your energy for building your actual application.

Using a GET request, your email:

> login/?email=myemail+job@gmail.com

Will look like: myemail job@gmail.com, since the [plus sign is shorthand for space.](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html)